# Mat-grid-tile with changing colspan and animation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-grid-list that has 3 inner mat-grid-tiles with same colspan of 1.
My purpose is to set an onclick function on each tile that the clicked tile's colspan becomes 3, while the other 2 tiles' colspans become 0; in addiction, I'd like to set a sort of animation or transition on the click, which show gradually the change of the colspan.
I have this code html:

```
  <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="150px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let tile of this.indexs" [attr.id]="'tile_' + tile"  
    [colspan]="widths[tile-1]" 
    [style.background]="colors[tile-1]"         
    (click)="this.collapse(tile)">

    </mat-grid-tile>
   
</mat-grid-list>
```

with this ts:

```
declare var $;

@Component({
    selector: "app-cc-tab-tdb",
    templateUrl: "./cc-tab-tdb.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./cc-tab-tdb.component.scss"],
})
export class CcTabTdbComponent implements OnInit {
    widths=[1,1,1];
    colors=["red","blue","green"];
    @Input() indexs;
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.indexs);
    }
    
    collapse(idx){
        this.indexs.forEach( i => {
                if(i==idx){
                    if(this.widths[i-1]!=3){
                        this.widths[i-1]=3
                    } else {
                        this.widths[i-1]=1
                    }
                } else {
                    if(this.widths[i-1]!=0){
                        this.widths[i-1]=0
                    } else {
                        this.widths[i-1]=1
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

As a result, I obtain the right colspans clicking on each tile, but I'd want to add the animation/transition. Besides, after the click, the mat-grid-list seems to add a new empty row:
[this is my situation before the click on the red tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRDQI.png), while I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCQ1N.png) after the click on the red tile.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: I forgot, my @Input() indexs is an array: [1, 2, 3]

Comment: ok, I found the way to obtain the animation:
I simply added these two classes to the tiles:
`.collapse-width{
    
    transition: width 1s ease!important;
    
}

.collapse-height{
    
    transition: height 1s ease!important;
    
}`
But I still obtain an empty row under the expanded tile